php.ini display_errors Off but phpinfo() says it's on...?
my host server is running centos 7 GNU/Linux, php 7.4.33, and Apache. I have display_errors = Off in both the plesk version of php and in the system version of php. I am still getting Warnings and phpinfo() shows display errors as 'On'. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is?
Thanks,

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
